# Scope with association and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord, scope

I have an app that records calls.  Each call can have multiple units associated with it.  Part of my app has a reports section which basically just does a query on the Call model for different criteria.  I've figured out how to write some scopes that do what I want and chain them to the results of my reporting search functionality.  But I can't figure out how to search by "unit". Below are relevant excerpts from my code:

```
Call.rb

    has_many :call_units
    has_many :units, through: :call_units

        #Report search logic
          def self.report(search)
            search ||= { type: "all" }

            # Determine which scope to search by
            results = case search[:type]
                      when "open"
                        open_status
                      when "canceled"
                        cancel
                      when "closed"
                        closed
                      when "waitreturn"
                        waitreturn
                      when "wheelchair"
                        wheelchair
                      else
                        scoped
                      end

#Search results by unit name, this is what I need help with.  Scope or express otherwise?          
results = results. ??????

            results = results.by_service_level(search[:service_level]) if search[:service_level].present?
            results = results.from_facility(search[:transferred_from]) if search[:transferred_from].present?
            results = results.to_facility(search[:transferred_to]) if search[:transferred_to].present?

            # If searching with BOTH a start and end date
            if search[:start_date].present? && search[:end_date].present?
              results = results.search_between(Date.parse(search[:start_date]), Date.parse(search[:end_date]))

              # If search with any other date parameters (including none)
            else
              results = results.search_by_start_date(Date.parse(search[:start_date])) if search[:start_date].present?
              results = results.search_by_end_date(Date.parse(search[:end_date])) if search[:end_date].present?
            end

            results
          end
```

Since I have an association for units already, I'm not sure if I need to make a scope for units somehow or express the results somehow in the results variable in my search logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want a scope that uses a join so you can use a `where` criteria in against the associated model? Is that correct?

So in SQL you're looking for something like

```
select * from results r 
    inner join call_units c on c.result_id = r.id 
    inner join units u on u.call_unit_id = c.id 
    where u.name = ?
```

and the scope would be (from memory, I haven't debugged this) something like:

```
scope :by_unit_name, lambda {|unit_name|
  joins(:units).where('units.unit_name = ?', unit_name)
}
```

units.name isn't a column in the db.  Changing it to units.unit_name didn't raise an exception and seems to be what I want.  Here's what I have in my results variable:

```
results = results.by_unit_name(search[:unit_name]) if search[:unit_name].present?
```

When I try to search by a different unit name no results show up.  Here's the code I'm using to search:

```
<%= select_tag "search[unit_name]", options_from_collection_for_select(Unit.order(:unit_name), :unit_name, :unit_name, selected: params[:search].try(:[], :unit_name)), prompt: "Any Unit" %>
```